# Iterating through a JSON decoded array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

A developer is sending me a multi-dimensional JSON array and it has an element/array that I cannot seem to get the info from. I have attached my code and a snippet of the decoded array.

```
    foreach($item['author'] as $sub){
    if (is_array($sub)){
        foreach($sub as $field => $value){
            if ($field == "name"){
                $author = $value;
            } elseif ($field == "Request"){
                $request = $value;
            } elseif ($field == "Phone"){
                $phone = $value;
....
```

The array is:

```
        Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field] => name
            [value] => John Smith
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [field] => Request
            [value] => order
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [field] => Phone
            [value] => 123-555-1212
        )
....
```

my $author, $request and $phone are coming up empty.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Jim

Comment: $field will equal 'field' not the value of 'field'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

field is a key and you want to check the value within it

```
foreach($item['author'] as $sub){
        if (is_array($sub)){
            foreach($sub as $field => $value){
                if ($sub[$field] == "name"){
                    $author = $sub[value];
                } elseif ($sub["$field"] == "Request"){
                    $request = $sub[value];
                } elseif ($sub[$field] == "Phone"){
                    $phone = $sub[$value];
    `
```

Comment: Other than a few typos, this worked.

$sub[$field] in the if statement and $sub['value'] in the variable assignment.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `$value` and not `$field`.

`$field` will be the 0,1,2 (INDEX) and so on..

So the solution will be:

```
foreach($a as $field => $value){
       if ($value['field'] == "name"){
            $author = $value['value'];
       }
}
```